# Joomla 3 $params->get returns NULL values in module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am writing a new module for Joomla! 3 and I am stumped by $params->get.

I can see the values in the database within the modules table, but the following code returns nothing for every parameter that have been set, including the default parameters of module_tag, bootstrap_size, header_tag, header_class, style.

The code is:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getParams();
$param = $params->get('module_tag');
```

When looking at the type of the variable $param, the type is retuned as NULL.

Joomla! 3.6.2
Stable PHP 5.6.18
MySQL 5.6.31

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the module name of which you would like to retrieve the parameters. Replace `'moduleName'` with the name of your module.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getParams('moduleName');
$param = $params->get('module_tag');
```

Comment: Please add an explanation what you've done and why it should fix OP's problem?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I had already tried that, even though the documentation says it is not necessary if calling from within the module. Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Can you share your module with me, so that I can debug the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Before getting params few points to note:

a. naming conventions
There are four basic files that are used in the standard pattern of module development:

```
mod_helloworld.php - This file is the main entry point for the module. 
mod_helloworld.xml - This file specifies configuration parameters for the module.
helper.php - This file do the actual work in retrieving the information  (usually from the database or some other source).
tmpl/default.php - This is the module template. This file will take the data collected by mod_helloworld.php and generate the HTML to be displayed on the page.
```

Check that both the mod_helloworld.php and mod_helloworld.xml names are same.

b. Your params will only show if you have saved it once.

Check this page before jumping to retrieve params https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module

There are two options

1. When calling from inside module use this in your mod_yourmodule.php file

   $module_tag = $params->get('module_tag', 'default value');

Then you can call $module_tag directly in your tmpl->default.php file

2. When calling from anywhere outside a module use this

   jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );

   $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('yourmodule');

   $moduleParams = new JRegistry($module->params);

   $module_tag = $moduleParams ['module_tag'];

   OR

   jimport('joomla.html.parameter');

   jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');

   $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('yourmodule');

   $moduleParams = new JRegistry();

   $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);

   $module_tag = $moduleParams->get('module_tag');

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am not sure how this addresses the issue. In 1 all you are doing is giving it a default value. I do not want a default value, I want the value already saved in the preferences. and 2 is not relevant as I am calling this from within the module

Comment: Try to understand the purpose of both. First one doesnt give a default value but returns the one already saved. If it is unable to get the saved value only than it returns the default value. In your own module itself if you are calling from helper.php file first one may not work but the second always works. From all this I presume you have not followed naming conventions. Might have made minor mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Thank your taking the time again.
My understanding is enough to understand what the commands do.  But the issue is that $params->get does not get the value from eh database. All the command does is to return the default value.  And I have been programming in other fields for over 25 years, so yes I did follow a naming convention for the files.  The code snippet was the test I was doing to get the initial parameter, and in all variations $params->get fails to return the stored value.

Comment: Can you upload the module somewhere so that I can check. There may be error in some files. Use a free upload service http://www.smashingapps.com/2009/05/22/6-more-free-file-hosting-websites-that-would-be-useful.html and paste the link here